# Travis-CI with a matrix running xcodebuild tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, travis-ci

I have a travis CI with the following Matrix:

```
env:
  matrix:
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator7.0 DESTINATION='platform=iOS Simulator,OS=7.0.3,name=iPhone 5'
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator7.1 DESTINATION='platform=iOS Simulator,OS=7.1,name=iPhone 5'
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator8.0 DESTINATION='platform=iOS Simulator,OS=8.0,name=iPhone 5'
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator7.0 DESTINATION='platform=iOS Simulator,OS=7.0.3,name=iPad Retina'
```

And a script:

```
script:
  - xcodebuild test -workspace SchemeNameiOS.xcworkspace -scheme SchemeNameiOS -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination $DESTINATION CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$PWD/build-test
```

But everytime I run it I get the following error: `xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '5'`.
When I look on the variables it is correctly showing `$ export DESTINATION='platform=iOS Simulator,OS=7.0.3,name=iPhone 5'`.

Any ideas on how to use the matrix to run tests on different platforms and devices? I can't set it without the matrix because the log size limit (4.5mb) and because it will be almost unreadable.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a workaround to the log size limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082444/how-to-work-around-travis-cis-4mb-output-limit

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
env:
  matrix:
   - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator7.0 OS=7.0.3 NAME='iPhone 5'
   - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator7.0 OS=7.1 NAME='iPhone 5'
   - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator8.0 OS=8.0 NAME='iPhone 5'
   - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator8.0 OS=7.0.3 NAME='iPad Retina'
```

And script:

```
script:
 - xcodebuild test -workspace SchemeNameiOS.xcworkspace -scheme SchemeNameiOS -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=$OS,name=$NAME" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$PWD/build-test
```