# Travis CI build fails for Bash script

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I've been trying to build my [my project](https://github.com/PandaLinux/pandaOS/tree/base) but `travis-ci` terminates the build due to the following reasons:

1. If there is lot of output in the terminal, the `log limit of 4Mb` exceeds and the `build` is terminated. I have tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082444/how-to-work-around-travis-cis-4mb-output-limit). This solution is also not helping me out as it produces the error explained in the next point.
2. If I reduce the verbosity, the build fails due to `No output recieved for 10mins`. To tackle this problem, I had used `travis_wait 60 <rest-of-the-cmd>`. But this command waits until the script exits. But in my case there is a main script which handles all the other scripts. So, using `travis_wait` in my case is of no use.

Is there any other way I can successfully pass all my builds?

You can find all my `builds` [here](https://travis-ci.org/PandaLinux/pandaOS/builds).

Comment: @tripleee This is not a duplicate question as I have tried solutions already answered by the community.

Comment: If yours is different, please explain how.  The obvious, highest-upvoted answer is to quelch the regular output and have a dummy job print something small every 9-odd minutes.  This will obviously still fail if the job is so long that it exceeds 40,000,000 minutes (when 10 minutes x 1 byte >= 4 MiB).  If yours is a complete duplicate and none of the answers make you happy, the way to revive an existing question is to post a bounty on it; though this requires more reputation than you currently have.  If you can articulate a good bounty criterion, I'll be happy to post one on your behalf.

Comment: @tripleee After implementing that solution, I get the `The job exceeded the maximum time limit for jobs, and has been terminated.`

Comment: That's a different problem all right, but your current question doesn't ask about that at all, and I would expect that too to be a duplicate.  If you can't find a suitable duplicate, maybe post a new question.