# How to make travis wait with a multiline script?

Tags: yaml, travis-ci

I need to modify a travis.yaml file where the command runs for long time, more than 10 minutes. The special in this script is that, it is a maven command where the ouput is redirected to a file, and the whole command runs more than 30 min.

Since, the ouput is redirected there is no output and due to that Travis kills the process after 10 minutes. Travis [doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received) suggest to use `travis_wait`, but I haven't found any example or something how to use it with multiline scripts.

With the examples below the result is that, the whole script part finishes within a few seconds, which is obviously bad. The mvn command only runs on my local machine for 40 minutes, and I except it to run something similar.

There are two reasons we want this:

- not dealing with maven's very long output
- avoid hitting Travis 4MB ouput limit

My script looks like this and the `mvn clean install` part should be waited.

```yaml
script:
  - |
    if [[ -z "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]]; then
      mvn clean install > output.txt
    fi
```

What I tried so far are below, without positive results. I have to mention that I'm pretty new in working with yaml files.

```yaml
script:
  - |
    travis_wait 40
    if [[ -z "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]]; then
      mvn clean install > output.txt
    fi
```

And

```yaml
script:
  - |
    if [[ -z "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]]; then
      travis_wait 40 mvn clean install > output.txt
    fi
```

Comment: You're saying that the output of the `mvn` command is redirected to a file, but your code does not show such a redirect. Also, there is no way we can tell whether the problem is choosing `40` as parameter when you only give us the information that the command runs *more than 30 minutes* – that could be 60 minutes, in which case giving `40` won't be enough.

Comment: @flyx thanks for pointing out the script doesn't reflect on what I said. It is fixed now. On my local machine the same mvn command takes 37 minutes to execute. I don't know the specifics of the machine travis uses, so 40 is only a try. And I forgot mention another thing, which is when I use `travis_wait 40` the whole command finishes within a few seconds, like the maven part wouldn't be executed or if it s spawned to another process travis isn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

`travis_wait` cannot help your command to do any output when you pipe its output to a file. Travis will still see no output from the command.

Assuming the command itself produces enough output (which it should), the easy fix is

```
mvn clean install | tee output.txt
```

This writes to `output.txt` *and* outputs to stdout so that Travis sees it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. The point is to make the mvn ouput disappear and have the ouput short, and have the devs deal with maven's very lengthy ouput when it is needed. I'll update my question accordingly. I haven't thought it through properly.

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26082445/347964) may be what you want.